# What is the difference between 字 and 文字?

Tags: synonyms

I was talking to someone about the etymology of the word "emoji" recently, and how it comes from [絵文字](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%B5%B5%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97) in Japanese.

I knew that [絵](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%B5%B5#Japanese) means "picture", and that [文字](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97#Japanese) means "character", but I was unable to explain why the [文](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%96%87#Japanese) kanji is necessary when [字](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AD%97#Japanese) also means "character" by itself.

Are 字 and 文字 interchangeable, or do they have different connotations/usage patterns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that this question has already been answered on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-%E5%AD%97-and-%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97), so - as per [this meta question](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/754/9212) - I'll provide an overview of what I've learned here:

- 字 and 文字 are, on their own, generally interchangeable.

  - Compare "phone" and "telephone" in English.
- However, this may not be the case with compounds.

  - For example, 漢字 is fine, but 漢文字 sounds strange.

**Trivia:** According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi), these kanji were (and maybe still are?) used to make a distinction between characters with a single radical and those with multiple radicals in Chinese:

> The title of the work draws a basic distinction between two types of characters, wén 文 and zì 字, the former being those composed of a single graphic element (such as shān 山 "mountain"), and the latter being those containing more than one such element (such as hǎo 好 "good" with 女 "woman" and 子 "child") which can be deconstructed into and analyzed in terms of their component elements.

However, I do not believe that this applies to modern Japanese (if it ever applied to Japanese at all).